# Dictionary containing two lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

There are existing two lists:

```
train = ['a','b','c']
test = ['d','e']
```

How do I get a dictionary that looks like this?

```
partition
{'train': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'test': ['d', 'e']}
```

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "get"? Get what, exactly? Are you talking about the names of the variables?

Comment: There: `partition = {'train': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'test': ['d', 'e']}`. I guess you had a different question in mind?

Comment: No, that's it :) Thanks! Or the solutions provided by the other colleagues ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
{"train": train, "test": test}
```

This results in

```
{'train': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'test': ['d', 'e']}
```

Answer (score 2):

`dict = {"train": train, "test": test}`
Will give you what you need.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest using the name of a built-in class as variable name. What if a try to create an empty dictionary `another_dict = dict()` after this?

Comment: Of course, I wouldn't use that name in real code either, it was just for the purpose of this example.